SELECT all the records in a table that have ALL the specified characteristics from another table
to be more specific, I have a table with a list of symptoms and a table with a list of diseases. I have also created a table to link a specific symptom to a specific disease. What I'm looking to do is returning all the diseases that have ALL the selected symptoms from the symptoms'table.
Symptom



id
symptom




1
Symp A


2
Symp B


3
Symp C


4
Symp D


5
Symp E



Disease



id
disease




1
Dss  A


2
Dss  B


3
Dss  C


4
Dss  D



Symptom_Disease



id
symp_id
dss_id




1
1
2


2
1
4


3
2
2


4
2
1


5
3
1


6
4
1



So, say I select the symptoms A and B (whose ids are 1 and 2), the only disease with both those symptoms is the disease B (id 2). Is there a way to write a single select (with its joins / nested SELECTS / whatsoever) to achieve this result?
I've tried something like:
SELECT * 
FROM `disease` 
LEFT JOIN symptom_disease ON symptom_disease.id_disease = disease.id
LEFT JOIN symptom ON symptom.id = symptom_disease.id_symptom 
WHERE symptom_disease.id_symptom = 1 
  AND symptom_disease.id_symptom = 2;

but of course it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Where does symptom_avaria table fit in?

"SELECT all the records in a table...", followed by "to be more specific", and *still not sharing desired output.  Should we guess what you really want ? Also "it doesn't work." is never a good description because it leaves a question (why does it not work, is it because of an error, or because of unexpected results)

@bugdrown that was a typo, fixed. Desired result is in the description: I would just like to retrieve the record(s) where all symptoms are present, not just anyone of them (which is why I cannot use an OR)

If you have symptoms A,B,C,D then you should also have diseases such as: symptoms A,B,C or A,B,D are displayed or only where everything fits exactly?

You can use a query like this:
SELECT 
    MAX(d.id) AS ID, 
    MAX(d.disease) AS Disease,    
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s.symptom,'(',s.id,')')) AS has_symptom
FROM 
    disease AS d
LEFT JOIN 
    sym2dss AS s2d ON d.id = s2d.dss_id
LEFT JOIN 
    symptom AS s ON s.id = s2d.symp_id
GROUP BY 
    d.id
HAVING 
    SUM(s2d.symp_id IS NOT NULL) = SUM(s2d.symp_id IN(2,3,4))
    AND SUM(s2d.symp_id IS NOT NULL) = 3;
  

NOTE: You only must change the last 2 lines with this symp ids and the number of symps
Sample:
SELECT 
    MAX(d.id) AS ID, MAX(d.disease) AS Disease, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s.symptom,'(',s.id,')')) AS has_symptom
FROM
    disease AS d
LEFT JOIN 
    sym2dss AS s2d ON d.id = s2d.dss_id
LEFT JOIN 
    symptom AS s ON s.id = s2d.symp_id
GROUP BY 
    d.id
HAVING 
    SUM(s2d.symp_id IS NOT NULL) = SUM(s2d.symp_id IN(2,3,4))
    AND SUM(s2d.symp_id IS NOT NULL) = 3;

Output:
1   Dss A   symptom D(4),symptom C(3),symptom B(2)

here is dbfiddle sample

Diseases that include both symptoms 1 and 2...
SELECT
  dss_id
FROM
  symptom_disease
WHERE
  symp_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
  dss_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2

Diseases that have exactly symptoms 1 and 2 (and no other additional symptoms)
SELECT
  dss_id
FROM
  symptom_disease
GROUP BY
  dss_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN symp_id IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) = 2


This answer avoids using ID's as criteria:
select dis.Disease, sym.Symptom
from Disease as dis
inner join Symptom_Disease as sym_dis
 on dis.ID=sym_dis.dss_ID
inner join Symptom as sym
 on sym.ID=sym_dis.Symp_ID
inner join
(select d.Disease, count(s.symptom) as CountOfSymptoms
from symptom_disease as sd
inner join Symptom as s
 on sd.Symp_ID = s.ID
inner join Disease as d
 on sd.dss_ID = d.ID
where s.Symptom = 'Symp A' or s.Symptom = 'Symp B' 
group by d.Disease
having count(s.symptom)>1) as g
 on dis.Disease=g.Disease


Ended up writing this
SELECT * FROM disease WHERE id = (
SELECT symptom_disease.id_disease
FROM symptom_disease 
WHERE symptom_disease.id_symptom IN (1,2)
GROUP BY symptom_disease.id_disease
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_disease.id_symptom) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM symptom
    WHERE symptom.id IN (1,2)));

   
and it seems to be working. Thank you all for the inspiration!
